Why does updating the state array in reactjs is not reflecting in my child component UI
After I receive the response from an API, I am trying to update my child component based on the response data. But the below code is not able to update the UI, and also when I added console in the child component, it looked like the child component is not getting re-rendered. Changes in props are only reflecting but not from the state array object.
Below code I am using from parent to render the child component based on array variable - dataSource
<div id='row-item-container'>
<p>This will render the tabular part</p>
{ this.state.dataSource.length>0 && <div id='trxBox'>
    {this.state.dataSource.map(exp=>(
        <ExpenseEditableBlock data={exp} onDataChange={this.handleDataChange}
        key={exp.TrxID} 
        onExpSelect={this.selectThisExpItem}
        readonly={this.state.validationRenderer}
        validFlag={exp.ValidFlag}
        style={{marginBottom: '5px'}}/>
    ))}
</div>}

Below setState I am using to update the dataSource variable in parent component for the child component
this.setState({dataSource: itemsParam});

Child Component:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import '../../CompCss/ExpenseEditableBlock.css';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import { Utils } from './../Utils';

const utils = Utils();

class ExpenseEditableBlock extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expenseData: props.data,
            categoryArray: [],
            _otherVarName_ : null,
            checked: false
        }

       console.log('props ----->',props,'\nProps data:',this.state.expenseData);

        utils.expCategories().forEach((item) => {
            this.state.categoryArray.push(item.label);
        });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={(this.state.expenseData.ValidFlag === "FAIL")?"exp-block-box-one disabled-item":"exp-block-box-one"} style={this.props.style}>
        <div id="exp-item-head-section">
            <div className="display-inline-block">
                <p>Trx ID: {this.state.expenseData.TrxID}</p>
                <p>{this.state.expenseData.ValidFlag}</p>  /*THIS IS NOT REFLECTING THE VALUE */
                <p>{this.props.validFlag}</p>  /*whereas THIS IS REFLECTING THE VALUE */
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div className="exp-date-block">{this.state.expenseData.TrxDate}</div>
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.expenseData.TrxTitle}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div style={{height: '3px'}}>
            {/* <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard" /> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ExpenseEditableBlock;

Below image for what I am trying to achieve


this.state.categoryArray.push() updates your state in place. You need to completely replace the array and add your new items from utils.expCategories() to the end of the new array, not modify the existing one.

See Updating Arrays in State from the react docs
